# To which extent should repetitions of "der", "die" and "das" be avoided?

Tags: article, personal-pronoun, style

When I speak, it often happens that pronoun/article homonyms crop up after each other.

> So viele Katzen! Ich mag die, die den Hut trägt.
>
> Ich mag die, die die Mütze trägt.
>
> Welches Kätzchen findest du am süßesten? Ich denke, dass das, das das Kleid trägt, am süßesten ist.

To which extent should such constructs be avoided in speech and writing?

Comment: I'd like a tag for questions like these, that do not concern grammar but still "correctness".

Comment: Ist das das das das, das das das so schwierig macht? ;)

Comment: @splattne: +1 for a classic, entirely valid German sentence. Though I'm not sure whether the 2nd, 4th and 7th should be capitalized :)

Comment: Aren't some of those supposed to be _dass_?

Comment: @OregonGhost agreed, but it looks more impressive this way. :) @Tim no, the das after the comma is a relative pronoun.

Comment: @Tim: No. There's a variant of the sentence that goes like *Ich weiß, dass das Das das Das ist....* though.

Comment: The last sentence sounds wrong, the other ones sound fine.

Comment: @Tim What about "style"?

Comment: @thei: I think the last sentence is about *das Kätzchen*.

Comment: @thei the last sentence is correct too. It could be an answer to: "Welches Hündchen findest du am süßesten?"

Comment: @OregonGhost @splattne: I tried to come up with a das-animal, but never thought of diminutives. Thanks, edited!

Comment: @OregonGhost: Yes, it is still true that I would absolutely regard the first two sentences as perfectly good style and the last one is strange, it would work in speech with very good stress.

Comment: @thei: That's another can of worms. Strange it may be, but correct it is.

Comment: @OregonGhost: The question is about style, not about grammatical correctness.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in it. Not even problematic. "Die Diebin die die Diestel stahl ...". Just let it flow. "Der derbe Derwisch, der der Dermatologin dergleichen derweil derart deregulierte, dass das Dasitzen, das das Dasein daselbst darstellt, öde ward, ist nun gegangen."

Comment: "Das! Das ist das Auto, das er sagte, dass er kaufen will."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You *can* use *welches* as pronoun:

> So viele Katzen! Ich mag die, welche den Hut trägt.
>
> Ich mag die, welche die Mütze trägt.
>
> Ich denke, dass das, welches das Kleid trägt, am süßesten ist.

I personally don't like the use of *welches* though and prefer duplicate *die, die*. Technically nothing wrong with that. If you don't like the duplication, you may change the sentence:

> Ich mag die mit dem Hut.
>
> Ich mag diejenige, die eine Mütze trägt.
>
> Ich finde, dass das kleidtragende Kätzchen am süßesten ist.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about using _welcher_ as a personal pronoun. Can I say/write "dass das, das das" without its being awkward?

Comment: @Tim: I'd try to avoid more than two duplicate words.

Comment: The one with the hat reminds me of the elefant with a hat in the board game *Kings & Things*. Don't do this to real kitties though. Please.

Comment: Was spricht gegen "Ich denke, dass jenes, welches das Kleid trägt, am süßesten ist."?

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek: Es klingt recht umständlich. Falsch ist es nicht. Abgesehen davon, dass es eher finden statt denken sein sollte ;)

Answer (score 4):

The repetitions of pronouns in the examples you provided actually sound perfectly fine to me. However, if you want to put it differently, you might want to try something like this:

> So viele Katzen! Ich mag die mit dem Hut.
>
> Ich mag die mit der Mütze.
>
> Welches Kätzchen findest du am süßesten? Ich denke, dass das mit dem Kleid am süßesten ist.

In spoken/colloquial German, you'll probably find these more often since they make a shorter sentence by avoiding the verb.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the first two sentences are quite natural, but the last one isn't (though grammatically correct and possible to say with very good stress).

"Welche" is correct, but not used much in informal speech.

Besides the excellent suggestions in the second part of OregonGhost's answers I want to point out that most people will repeat the noun if the number of repetitions is too high.

Comment: Repeat as in "dass das Kätzchen, das das"? That's a nice solution.

Comment: @Tim: Yes, exactly.

Comment: +1: True, the noun may also be repeated. Note that you typically don't repeat the same noun or verb too often in written German (as my Technical English professor put it, for the sake of *Abwechslung*). You may of course also use a synonym instead. Though I didn't mention it in my answer, my third alternative example actually just repeats the noun, without me realizing it. Guess that happened because it just felt unnatural, as thei said ;)